# Transfer Google Drive site to Google Sites

Tags: google-drive, google-classic-sites

Can I get my [Google Drive site](https://5e951c14064973bf83b51818d7c43173152ca8f3.googledrive.com/host/0B0FDz6Brn925LVVpSDNvME92Rkk/Introduction/) switched over to Google Sites with it being the same? Can I directly code in Google Sites? If so, how?

Comment: I haven't used it in a while, but I am pretty sure you can link to documents in Sties.

Answer (score 1):

A web site hosted in a web site hosting service can't be transferred directly to Google Sites as it's not a "regular" web site hosting service ( host html, image, css, javascript, etc. files), but you you could transfer the content and some code.

Regarding directly coding in Google Sites, you could edit the content of the pages by editing HTML code but there a limitations. There is the option to use the HTML Box tool to insert HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Also you could use [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/)

More detailed information in the help articles in references.

**References**

From the [Google Sites Help](https://support.google.com/sites/)

- [Editing your site](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/153196?hl=en)
- [Insert custom HTML, CSS, and Javascript](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en)
- [Guide to automating actions with Apps Scripts](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224162?hl=en)